# How to show one JSON Object per ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I am working on a short news app. It's parsed JSON from a URL. I want to show one news per view pager.on swipe on next `ViewPager`, I want to show next news like the list. How can I can do that with `ViewPager`?

Comment: You can load fragments in ViewPager and each fragment can fetch it's required information. Here are some links to get started. 

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/updating-viewpager-with-new-data-dynamically/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824429/populate-each-fragment-in-viewpager-with-different-json-object-without-loading-a

Answer (score 2):

Set JSON data to PagerAdapter as we set to Base Adapter or other adapters & create custom layout for adapter.

> view_pager_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loutPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/loutCirIndicator"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loutCirIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:ci_drawable="@drawable/bg_selected_indicator"
                app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/bg_unselected_indicator" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> row_pager_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="abc" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

> ViewPager Adapter

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    List<Response_Model> Arr_ResultList;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public SamplePagerAdapter(final Activity activity,final  List<Response_Model> Arr_ResultList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.Arr_ResultList = Arr_ResultList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Arr_ResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        final int pos = position;

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_pager_item, container, false);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            Glide.with(activity).load(Arr_ResultList.get(pos).getImage())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageView);

            textView.setText(Arr_ResultList.get(pos).getName());


        container.addView(view);

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

> Set Pager Adapter to ViewPager

```
SamplePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, Arr_Result_List);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: do you have a GitHub repository link. please add.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PagerAdapter` for `ViewPager` and create your custom xml layout and 
set your view on cell by position. Pass your list into pager adapter in adapter constructor.

You can refer this link it will be help you.

- https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial